# Is there a way to sum a product of two columns in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, join, sum

Here are my tables:

```
-- receipts
| id | date       |
|----|------------|
| 1  | 2016-12-20 |
| 2  | 2016-12-20 |
| 3  | 2016-12-21 |

-- purchases
| id | receipt_id | item        | price | tax_rate |
|----|------------|-------------|-------|----------|
| 1  | 1          | apples      |  3.89 | 0.000    |
| 2  | 1          | canned soup |  2.99 | 0.095    |
| 3  | 1          | candy bar   |  0.99 | 0.095    |
| 4  | 2          | gas         | 26.78 | 0.000    |
| 5  | 3          | chips       |  3.99 | 0.095    |
| 6  | 3          | dip         |  2.99 | 0.095    |
```

I am trying to do a query that returns the 3 items from the receipts table with the subtotal, the total tax, and the grand total. This is what I have for the SQL so far.

```
SELECT 
    receipts.id, 
    receipts.date, 
    SUM(purchases.price) AS subtotal, 
    SUM(purchases.price * purchases.tax_rate) AS tax,
    SUM(subtotal + tax_rate)
FROM receipts
RIGHT JOIN purchases ON purchases.receipt_id = receipts.id;
```

The end result should look like this:

```
| id | date       | subtotal | tax  | total |
|----|------------|----------|------|-------|
| 1  | 2016-12-20 |  7.87    | 0.38 |  8.25 |
| 2  | 2016-12-20 | 26.78    | 0.00 | 26.78 |
| 3  | 2016-12-21 |  6.98    | 0.66 |  7.64 |
```

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: The `SUM(subtotal + tax)` is giving me and error that says `Unknown column 'subtotal' in 'field list'` If I remove that one I get I don't get any errors but it just returns the first row and sums the entire column into that one row.

Comment: You can't refer to a field alias in the same query. You either need to put it into a subquery, or repeat the calculation of that alias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a case for an `INNER JOIN`, and you need to `GROUP BY` receipt_id. The rest looks fine, except for what shmosel has answered.

```
SELECT 
    receipts.id, 
    receipts.date, 
    SUM(purchases.price) AS subtotal, 
    SUM(purchases.price * purchases.tax) AS tax,
    SUM(purchases.price) + SUM(purchases.price * purchases.tax) AS total
FROM receipts
INNER JOIN purchases ON purchases.receipt_id = receipts.id
GROUP BY receipt_id
```

mysql is not aware of generated aliases, you need to write the calculations in the select clause for every select, and hope that mysql handles it right and doesn't calculate everything twice.

Comment: The `INNER JOIN` worked but it also worked with the `RIGHT JOIN`. but not using the aliases and adding the group by got it working.

Comment: The INNER JOIN is the what you are looking for, as it would lead to errors if you use RIGHT JOIN and handle the data further in a program. Typically, there can't be a receipt without a purchase and vice versa. The INNER JOIN finds "valid" entries only, having both a receipt and a purchase. @MakPo

Comment: @baao - As written right now, your SQL statement is invalid because you are neither aggregating nor grouping by receipts.date. [Caleb Haldane's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41292360/1429354) is more correct and better explains the requirements of aggregating data.

Comment: It's not needed to group by both columns. @andymerts

Comment: I missed that this was MySQL, where this is allowed.  I stand corrected.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there.  Since you are wanting to aggregate your results, you need to use the aggregate function SUM (which you have done), but when you use SUM you need to tell the query how you want to aggregate the data.  You do this by Adding a Group By Statement.

```
SELECT 
    receipts.id, 
    receipts.date, 
    SUM(purchases.price) AS subtotal, 
    SUM(purchases.price * purchases.tax) AS tax,
    SUM(purchases.price) + SUM(purchases.price * purchases.tax) AS total
FROM receipts
RIGHT JOIN purchases ON purchases.receipt_id = receipts.id;
GROUP BY receipts.id, receipts.date
```

Answer (score 1):

The third `SELECT` value should be

```
SUM(purchases.price) + SUM(purchases.price * purchases.tax) AS total
```